# How to interact with a smart contract which is deployed in a quorum network (Alastria)?

Tags: private-blockchain, contract-invocation, quorum

I have already deployed the contract using tuffle in my private network. Now, I would like to know what i have to do to interact with the contract.
I don't need ethers in my wallet and actually i don't have it because it is a quorum network and the gas price is 0.
How could I interact with the contract?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like how you do in ethereum. Get the mined address for your contract. Search for the logs wherever your submitted it. Or simply use eth.getTransaction(transctionHash) and you will see contractAddress property in that.

Simply,

```
> var address="yourcontractaddress"
> var abi =[your contract abi]
> var p = eth.contract(abi).at(address)
```

now p.yourfunction() simply interact using the var p.

You can paste your contract here on http://remix.ethereum.org. Click on compile. Then click on details. Scroll. You will see ABI. Copy that(there is a small copy icon there where it is written ABI) and use that for your var abi. You can also use web3 deploy in same Details to deploy your smart contract on the blockchain.

Comment: sorry, use eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash) to get the address for your contract